# Partials not transferring local variable correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is totally confusing to me. The error message is telling me that user is undefined and I know I am passing it correctly. I have done this same operation before and never seen this error message. What am I doing wrong?

landings/show.html.erb
[image]

[http://imgur.com/BFyhYOB](https://imgur.com/BFyhYOB)
[image]

Error:
[image]

EDIT
Sessions controller:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you're looking at the wrong template.  look at line 13 of sessions_controller.  that's where your issue comes from.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out jvnill. I don't see anything wrong with the way it is though, it makes sense to me. I uploaded an image of what I have, can you see what i'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: like the answers posted here, your issue is that the local variable `user` is not defined when you render the partial.  so just add that.  `render partial: 'landings/error_messages', locals: { user: @user }, target: @user, status: 404`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the variables in a locals hash and call using partial helper.

```
render partial: "error_messages", locals: {user: @user}
```

Now you should be able to access `user` within the partial.

Comment: Still getting them same error message mate. Could I be passing it from the controller incorrectly?

Comment: if that is the case, you would get 'nil'